# Fail to login Google Play Game Services

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I set up my game on Developer Console with package name and right signing certificate and created a leaderboard for it (but no achievements was created).

Then, I downloaded the sample "Type A Number Challenge" and "BaseGameUtils" from https://developers.google.com/games/services/downloads/

After that, I modified the package name, leaderboard ID, application ID in "Type A Number Challendge", removed the code regarding achievement, generate the apk file with the right signing certificate and test it.

However, the following dialog was prompted when I try to login Google+ on my phone:

**"The application is incorrectly configured. Check that the package name and signing certificate match the client ID created in Developer Console. Also, if the application is not yet published, check that the account you are trying to login with is listed as a tester account. See logs for more information."**

Refer to the logs on Eclipse, the package name, application ID and signing certificate match my setting on Google Console and the account I tried to login was listed on tester list.

I also published the application, however, the same dialog still prompted.

May I know if I missed something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few things to try:

Double-check that the APK is getting signed with the right certificate. Even if you're sure that it is :-) Here's an example command line:

```
unzip YourGame.apk
keytool -printcert -file META-INF/CERT.RSA
```

See if the fingerprint printed in the `SHA1` line matches what you entered in Developer Console.

Next, double-check your metadata tags on your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. You should have:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
    android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

And, of course, you should have a corresponding string in `res/values/strings.xml` with your app ID:

```
<string name="app_id">123456789012</string>
```

Make sure this app ID contains *only digits*. It is an error to include ".apps.googleusercontent.com" here!)

Also, make sure the account on your test phone is listed in the **Testers** section of the developer console (but you said you published  your app, so this shouldn't matter... but check it anyway).

For other troubleshooting tips, check out our [troubleshooting guide](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting).

Comment: It seems from your checklist that you probably already looked through the following link, but if not: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting.

Comment: Also check: did you use Google Play Developer Console (correct approach) vs the Google Developer Console. https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#step_3_generate_an_oauth_20_client_id "Warning: Do not create new client IDs for your game from the Google Developers Console. If you do so, Google Play games services will not associate your game settings with the client ID, and this could cause errors during gameplay." Initially, I found this very confusing, but it makes sense: just use the prompts in the Google PLAY Developers Console (not Developers Console).