# Can't login into google play game services API

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm desperately trying to setup an android game to use Google Play Game Services SDK.

After following the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html), I based my code on [this example](https://github.com/TheInvader360/libgdx-gameservices-tutorial). Calling the login results in this error, in the logs:

```
01-31 12:06:54.580: E/Volley(1853): [6153] qt.a: Unexpected response code 403 for   https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/110100128023441368674
01-31 12:06:54.612: E/SignInIntentService(1853): Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.
```

Alas, the API for my project exists in the API console ( https://cloud.google.com/console/project ), it contains the correct SHA1 footprint of my certificate, and it has been created automatically when I registered my project in the Android Dev Console here ( https://play.google.com/apps/publish ).

I've checked what is suggested in the SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369766/fail-to-login-google-play-game-services), to no avail...

I don't know if it is related, but i have a weird bug where the Terms&Conditions acceptation popup keep reappearing sporadically (even after a full browser cache cleanup), like it didn't register my acceptation or something.

For reference, this is my android manifest (I made sure that `@string/app_id` matches the  App ID in the Developper Console (147029020397), and that the sdk version is included in the metadatas) :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pokware.jb"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false">

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" android:value="@string/app_id" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.pokware.jb.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, after a couple of dozen attempts, I finally managed to make it work.

There was no error in my setup, but I suspect my many previous failed attempts introduced bad data in the application cache of my phone.

I cleared the cache of the Google Play Service app (in the Settings android system menu), manually installed my production APK (instead of running the dev version signed with the debug certificate in eclipse), ran it once, and then launched the dev version again inside Eclipse (overwriting the manually installed prod app). The miraculous "Welcome" popup then appeared !

Comment: Same happened to me. Didn't manage to clear the cache (the Clear Cache button wouldn't do anything), but after removing the application and installing the signed one, everything worked.

Comment: Genius you've just made me a millionaire mate!